# Reason for two ground planes in PCB for Voltage regulator

Tags: pcb, voltage-regulator, ground

I am trying to expand a PCB I created in the past with EAGLE to add a voltage regulator (LMZ31503). However, in the voltage regulator's schematics provided by the manufacturer, two different ground planes are used, one denoted by the parallel lines sign (PGND) and the other one by the big arrow (AGND). These are eventually connected. What is the reason for these two planes, what would it change if I used a single GROUND plane for both of them?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you created a PCB in the past and the schematics confuse you, how are we going to help?

Comment: Sorry, this was a bad explanation from me, I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this device (LMZ31503) they seperate power and analogue grounds so that any heavy duty power currents don't pass through the analogue ground and compromize device stability, output ripple or noise.

A single point connection ensures that power currents cannot pass through the analogue ground island.

Comment: You probably should add an advice to follow manufacturer's recommenced PCB layout for this device. Always :-) The datasheet contains an example.

Comment: @AliChen you just did that for me but realistically anyone trying to use this device has to read the datasheet and there, for everyone to see, towards the back of the document, is the recommended layout.

Comment: Andy: In theory everyone should read and follow datasheets, but the reality of StackExchange shows numerous examples of "inventive engineering" in area of switcher designs, including 0.2mm-wide traces in high-current paths.